# Google Cloud will be Sponsoring Database Administrators SE

Tags: discussion, featured, site-sponsorship

We're excited to announce that Google Cloud will be sponsoring Database Administrators Stack Exchange April 2nd through June 30th, in the United States and Canada. We wanted to give you a heads-up and walk you through what it will look like.

### How and where will the sponsorship be displayed?

For users in the US and Canada, the sponsorship will be visible on the right side of the header at the top of the site in a manner that's similar to the image below, which shows how the sponsorship appears on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), one of the other sites Google Cloud is currently sponsoring.

[image: image of Cross Validated SE home page with Google Cloud sponsorship logo in top right]

### What else changes?

Nothing! Quoting from [the original MSE announcement on sponsorships](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307861/site-sponsorships-bringing-resources-back-to-stack-exchange):

> First — sponsors do not own these Q&A sites. Sponsors work alongside our communities who ultimately build these sites. Communities ask the questions; communities create the tags; communities conduct elections as they do now, and we are not renaming our current sites like a garish sport stadium to the highest bidder. Any ads a sponsor submits still have go through our crazy-strict ad editorial process… as it has always been. Companies do not have access to personal data, and all Q&A content remains irrevocably licensed under Creative Commons for sharing and attribution.

Sponsorships are a tool that our clients can use to let folks who would be interested in their products know about them.

### What if I think I've found a design glitch/bug?

If something looks off, please report it as a [bug](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug) so we can investigate and squash it.

That's it! If you have any other questions or concerns, please leave them as answers below.

And lastly, thank you. These types of partnerships help us bring more resources to our communities, and they wouldn't be possible without the work you've put into making this site successful.